# Build UWP apps/library on build server

Tags: msbuild, uwp, build-server

I tried build UWP library on build server with MSBuild 2015 Tools. I have installed Windows 10 SDK and other needed tools, but I haven't Visual Studio 2015. When I try build with this command:

```
msbuild mySolution.sln /t:Rebuild/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x86;AppxBundlePlatforms=x86;AppxBundle=Always
```

or try this examples:
[compilebuild-the-uwp-project-from-command-line](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/compilebuild-the-uwp-project-from-command-line/), is still not working and I got errors:

```
...
error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Boolean' is not defined or imported 
error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported 
error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported 
error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Int32' is not defined or imported 
error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported 
error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Boolean' is not defined or imported 
error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Boolean' is not defined or imported
...
```

When I install VS, everything is ok, but I don't want install VS on build server.

Is it possible build UWP library/apps without Visual Studio?

Comment: i think you first need to do a nuget restore. think the .net core packages are missing

Comment: and this is good documentation too https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/auto-build-package-uwp-apps

Comment: I tried with nuget restore, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pack and restore are now msbuild targets (2017).
try msbuild /t:restore and then msbuild.
Run this from a admin cmd prompt

Comment: I would expect that msbuild /t:restore (and build) should work without elevation

Comment: When I try this solution, i get `error MSB4057: The target "restore" does not exist in the project. ` Do I need add some restore target to project?

Comment: when I said (2017), I meant Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: But I don't want install VS 2017 on Build Server.

Comment: Sorry. It was my incomprehension. I realize that Build Tool 2017 was released! I cannot found him unitl yesterday. When I used `nuget.exe restore` and new `msbuild` everything is working. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

Your need to ensure that the build machine runs `<path_to_nuget.exe>\nuget.exe restore` on the solution folder before running the `msbuild` command!

That will download all the nuget packages required by your solution!

`Nuget.exe` is not part of Visual Studio or the Windows SDK, so you might have to download it to the server first (or ensure you have a build script that does that for you)